# Custom URL for Component Search Results

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef, cms

I am writing to seek help displaying custom results in a SEF URL on Joomla CMS.

This is an example url with a customized search:

```
https://example.com/search.html?search=IT&exf_5=1&exf_4=-1&option=com_jomclassifieds&view=search&Itemid=147
```

I would like to display this link as:

```
https://example.com/today-walkins-in-hyderabad.html
```

I am using https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jom-classifieds/ as the extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired output using https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sh404sef/. The website in question now shows the predefined search results in custom URLs.

Here are a few of them which I was able to achieve:

1. Original URL:

   ```
   https://example.com/search.html?search=&exf_5=2&exf_4=-1&option=com_jomclassifieds&view=search&Itemid=147
   ```

   SEF URL:

   ```
   https://example.com/jobs-in-bangalore.html
   ```
2. Original URL:

   ```
   https://example.com/search.html?search=&exf_5=1&exf_4=-1&option=com_jomclassifieds&view=search&Itemid=147
   ```

   SEF URL:

   ```
   https://example.com/today-walkins-in-hyderabad.html
   ```

It even works for the links where the keywords are searched.  For example, I searched for the keyword "fresher" and have set the page to render on custom URL:

The actual link was:

```
https://example.com/search.html?search=fresher&exf_5=-1&exf_4=-1&option=com_jomclassifieds&view=search&Itemid=147
```

SEF URL:

```
https://example.com/fresher-jobs.html
```

Comment: I have redacted the domains in your answer.  This is a general Stack Exchange policy to prevent posts being used to improve search engine results. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186529/352329 The domain was not necessary to the solution, so this is a suitable edit. (I'll edit the question as well.)  Please award your answer the big green tick since you have resolved your own question.